# how can i trace if there is existing value in listview except the line that is editing VB6

Tags: vb6

my problem is how can i detect if there is existing value in the listview except the one that you will edit?

For Example of data in listview:

01     ALARM1      10:00:00 AM

02     ALARM2      11:00:00 AM

03     ALARM3      12:00:00 PM

what if i click the line ALARM2 to edit but i`ve change my mind and click the save button without anything changes. the program will not detect it has duplicate. but if i change the value of ALARM2 into ALARM3 with the same time, it will detect as duplication. thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

To validate your List control data, you can implement the `Validate` event in order to control and maintain the coherency of your data.

```
Private Sub listControl_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
If duplicate in my control Then
   Cancel=True
Else
   Cancel=False
End If
End Sub
```